# Is there a way to vectorize selection of columns (with repetition) from a matrix?

Tags: r, matrix, vectorization

I have a matrix L of size `n x k` and a vector Z of size `p`. Z is composed of integers which represent the column indices of L. I want to create a matrix X of size `n x p` which is the aggregation of the corresponding columns of L selected based on the values in Z.

```
Z = c(1, 3, 1, 2)
L = matrix(c(73,50,4,14,87,5,34,51,17,57,47,65),nrow=4)
> L
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   73   87   17
[2,]   50    5   57
[3,]    4   34   47
[4,]   14   51   65
```

I want X to be

```
> X
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   73   17   73   87
[2,]   50   57   50    5
[3,]    4   47    4   34
[4,]   14   65   14   51
```

In my original data, `p`, `k` and `n` are quite big (30K, 500 and 2K, respectively), and a loop over all Z values to select and combine the columns from L takes a very long time. Can there be a vectorized way (no loops) to do this task?

Comment: Pretty sure this is just `L[,Z]` - R doesn't care if you have repeating column indexes when you do selections from most objects.

Comment: You mention aggregation but your output is just as what @thelatemail suggests. Is there another step?

Comment: @thelatemail Wow, that's great, thanks!! I did not try regular indexing because for some reason I was sure it would not work with repeating indices. Sometimes just trying even if you don't have any hope makes sense, looks like..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure this is just:

```
L[,Z]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]   73   17   73   87
#[2,]   50   57   50    5
#[3,]    4   47    4   34
#[4,]   14   65   14   51
```

R doesn't care if you have repeating column indexes when you do selections from most objects.